# Design of Drawerlayout is not displaying in preview of android studio 3.0.1

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Design of Drawerlayout is not displaying in preview of android studio 3.0.1

And Same issue also with recycleview, NavigationView, android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.

See Screenshot

In Gradle I have Used :

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'

compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 23
versionCode 32
versionName "3.8(Indevelopemnt)"
```

**I already tried Clean, Rebuild, Invalidate Caches/Restart.**

Please Help me out.
Thanks in advance.

[image: Screenshot of preview of drawerlayout]

Comment: clean , rebuild , restart android studio

Comment: @VishvaDave I have Done but not solved.

Comment: try to change the device from nexus one to some other

Comment: @AbdulKawee I have also try with different device with different API Levels but not solved.

Answer (score 0):

you need to update your libraries to last version(or nearly last):

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
```

and compileSdk:

```
compileSdkVersion 27
```